# How to add user register option in moodle website on front page?

Tags: moodle

I am trying to develop a website in moodle. Now I want to give users an option. It should display on the website frontpage, so can anybody tell me how to do this task in moodle?

I am using Moodle 2.6 version and using clean theme.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Administration->plugins->authentication->manage authentication and select email based self registration from self registration dropdown. Then user will able to self register in application.